# Import csv perform searching without the use of opencsv

Tags: java, csv, random, collections

I want to import csv file without using opencsv and store those data in collection. From that collection draw any random data and show it on the screen. (Using java pre-defined packages only. Not opencsv)

```
package panellist;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
public class PanelList {
private static Random r = new Random();
private static int rand;
private static int endRange = 20;
private static List<Integer> randomNumber;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Ankit\\Desktop\\Book2.csv";
File file = new File(fileName); // TODO: read about File Names
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap map = new HashMap();
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
int i =0;



try {
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    while (inputStream.hasNext()){
        String data = inputStream.next();
        System.out.println("test="+data/*.startsWith("a")*/);
        map.put(i++,data);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data,",");  
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {  
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());  
 }
    }
    inputStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Printing HashMap:");
System.out.println(map);

endRange = map.size()-1;
for(int j=0;j<endRange;j++){
    rand = r.nextInt(endRange);
    System.out.println(map.get(r));
}



System.out.println(endRange);
rand = r.nextInt(endRange);           
       do
        {
           rand = r.nextInt(endRange);
        }
        while(randomNumber.contains(rand));

        randomNumber.add(rand);    
            Object x= randomNumber.get(randomNumber.size()-1);
       System.out.println(x);


}

}
```

Comment: Besides: this is **not** a question. You posted some requirements, and some code; but you didn't tell us anything about how we are supposed to help you. Do the work for you?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you expect something different to happen?

Comment: i got these exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

&

at panellist.PanelList.main(PanelList.java:69)
C:\Users\Ankit\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't do this.

Long answer:

- Do **not** re-invent the wheel.
- Do **not** assume that your "csv parser" will be *better* than opencsv, or any other existing csv-parsing library.
- To the contrary: it is very safe to assume that *your* implementation will be throw up, as soon as you give it some reasonable complex csv input.

If we are talking "school assignment is about writing your own CSV parser"; then I suggest: spend quite some time **studying** the many potential contents that [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files can surprise you with. Then you maybe look out how other people have solved such problems. Than you sit down; and the first thing to do would be to realize that simply tokenizing on ',' will not do it (by far).

( you see, there is a **reason** why most people prefer to use for this undertaking - and that is: it is **not an easy task** )

Comment: i am really thankful for your suggestion but as you had mentioned this is a school project. I am supposed to import a csv file and randomly draw any record (Conditions should be fulfilled). and the following person is going to take the internal viva. after a week i have to reload the list.